# Cannot mock @PreAuthorize when using with OAuth2 in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to write a **Unit** tests for all of my service classes, but I cannot find a solution on how to mock a **@PreAuthorize** above my controller methods. As an example:

I have this function in controller:

```
@GetMapping("/users")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers() {
    return service.getUsers();
}
```

And this in my service class:

```
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userRepository.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

WebSecurity class:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http = http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    http = http
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and();
    http = http
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(
                    (request, response, ex) -> response.sendError(
                            HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                            ex.getMessage()
                    )
            )
            .and();

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter());
}

public JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    JwtAuthenticationConverter converter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();

    converter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwt ->
            Optional.ofNullable(jwt.getClaimAsStringList("permissions"))
                    .stream()
                    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                    .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );

    return converter;
}
```

Now I am trying to write a unit test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class UserControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @Test
    @WithMockJwtAuth(claims = @OpenIdClaims(otherClaims
            = @Claims(stringClaims = @StringClaim(name = "permissions", value = "{ADMIN}"))))
    public void getAllUsers_shouldBeSuccess() throws Exception {
        ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        users.add(new User("0", true, new Role("USER")));

        when(userService.getUsers()).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.OK));

        mvc.perform(get("/users"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

But I receive an error on `mvc.perform` call:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: `org/springframework/security/web/context/SecurityContextHolderFilter`
```

**UPDATE:**

I've tried https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons and added `@WithMockBearerTokenAuthentication`, but I still receive the same error. Also to note: if I removed all `@` and left only with `@Test` above the method, I receive `401` error.

```
@Test
@WithMockBearerTokenAuthentication(attributes = @OpenIdClaims(otherClaims
        = @Claims(stringClaims = @StringClaim(name = "permissions", value = "{ADMIN}"))))
public void getAllUsers_shouldBeSuccess() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    users.add(new User("0", true, new Role("USER")));

    when(userService.getUsers()).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.OK));

    mvc.perform(get("/users"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Comment: This is not directly related to the (current) error you face, but as you configured a `JwtAuthenticationConverter` which populates the security-context with a `JwtAuthenticationToken`, you should use `@WithMockJwtAuth` (as per the answer) and not `@WithMockBearerTokenAuthentication` which, as its name let you guess, configures test security context with a `BearerTokenAuthentication` (default `Authentication` implementation for OAuth2 resource-server with **introspction**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, spring-security team chose to include in test framework MockMvc request post-processors and WebTestClient request mutators only, which limits OAuth2 authentication mocking to **controllers** unit-tests.

Hopefully, I kept my work on test annotations in a set of libs I publish on maven-central: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons. You can test any `@Component` with it (sample adapted from [here](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/samples/webmvc-jwtauthenticationtoken/src/test/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/samples/webmvc_jwtauthenticationtoken/MessageServiceTests.java)):

```java
//---------------------------------------------------//
// Test secured @Component which isn't a @Controller //
//---------------------------------------------------//

// Import web-security configuration and tested component class
@Import({ SampleApi.WebSecurityConfig.class, MessageService.class })
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class MessageServiceTests {

    // Auto-wire tested component
    @Autowired
    private MessageService messageService;

    // Mock tested component dependencies
    @MockBean
    GreetingRepo greetingRepo;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        when(greetingRepo.findUserSecret("ch4mpy")).thenReturn("Don't tel it");
    }

    @Test()
    void greetWitoutAuthentication() {
        // Call tested component methods directly (don't use MockMvc nor WebTestClient)
        assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> messageService.getSecret("ch4mpy"));
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockJwtAuth(authorities = "ROLE_AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL", claims = @OpenIdClaims(preferredUsername = "ch4mpy"))
    void greetWithMockJwtAuth() {
        assertThat(messageService.getSecret("ch4mpy")).isEqualTo("Don't tel it");
    }
}
```

#### Edit for updated question

Only `@Controller` unit-tests should run within the context of an HTTP request.

This means that `@WebMvcTest` (or `@WebFluxTest`) and `MockMvc` (or `WebTestClient`) must be used in `@Controller` tests **only**.

Unit-tests for any other type of `@Component` (`@Service` or `@Repository` for instance) should be written without the context of a request. This means that none of `@WebMvcTest`, `@WebFluxTest`, `MockMvc`and `WebTestClient` should be used in such tests.

The sample above shows how to structure such tests:

- Trigger spring-context configuration
- `@Import` web-security configuration and your `@Component` class
- provide `@MockBean` for all of your `@Component` dependencies
- in the test, call tested component methods directly (do not try to create a mockMvc request)

#### Edit for the 2nd question modification

> I am trying to write a Unit tests for all of my service classes

Apparently, this first statement is not your main concern anymore as you're trying to write **integration-tests** for `@Controller` along with the `@Services`, `@Repositories` and other `@Components` it is injected. This is actually a completely different question than **unit-testing** each of those separately (mocking others).

`NoClassDefFoundError` on `SecurityContextHolderFilter` means that `spring-security-web` is not on your classpath. It should be, even during the tests. Check your dependencies (pom or gradle file that you did not include in your question)

Please also note that:

- you might want to write `value = "ADMIN"` instead of `value = "{ADMIN}"` (unless you really want curly-braces in your authority name)
- you can use just `@WithMockJwtAuth("ADMIN")` instead of `@WithMockJwtAuth(claims = @OpenIdClaims(otherClaims = @Claims(stringClaims = @StringClaim(name = "permissions", value = "ADMIN"))))`
- **you are allowed to read docs** (you and I would save quite some time). This includes [Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/index.html) and mine: [home one](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) and more importantly [tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials)

Comment: Hi, thanks for an answer. I've tried adding `@WithMockBearerTokenAuthentication` via `@Claims` but I still receive the same error. P.S: If I removed all `@` and left only with `@Test` above the method, I receive `401` error. Please see updated post. Thanks.

Comment: If you get a 401, it means that you are in the context of an http request. If you are testing a `@Controller`, you should be using `@WebMvcTest` along with auto-wired `MockMvc`. If you are testing any other kind of `@Component` (`@Service` or `@Repository` for instance), **do NOT use `MockMvc` nor `@WebMvcTest`** . Look carefully at the service test in the answer, it doesn't.

Comment: As I understand, when I received 401 error that's good, because I ran a test without providing an authentication mock, thus I could write a test which should catch a 401 when user is not authenticated. Now I've just updated to use `WithMockJwtAuth`. Changing to `@WebMvcTest` throws `Failed to load ApplicationContext`. I've tried removing UserService calls, but with that `@WithMockJwtAuth` I receive those context errors. Please see my updated test class. Thanks.

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Excellent. Everything works now as I expected, thanks.